How to animate an Animated Vector Drawable on a Fragment page in Android Kotlin?
I am trying to learn Android Kotlin, going thru some of the examples and tutorials.
I am struck halfway to add a  project with a simple animation on a fragment page
Below is the animation code:
fun ImageView.applyLoopingAnimatedVectorDrawable(
    @DrawableRes animatedVector: Int,
    endDelay: Long = 0,
    disableLooping: Boolean = false
) {
    val animated = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, animatedVector)

    if (!disableLooping) {
        animated?.registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    this@applyLoopingAnimatedVectorDrawable.post { animated.start() }
                }, 
                endDelay)
            }
        })
    }
    this.setImageDrawable(animated)
    animated?.start()
}

Here is part of the fragment xml file with the imageview:
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_progress"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/animated_progress_bar" />

Can someone please show me the code on the fragment kotlin page to get the animation working
